# Parsing Python HTML POST data from BaseHTTPServer

Tags: python, http, post, basehttpserver

I'm sending a couple of files from an HTML form to my server which is based on BaseHTTPServer.

Within my do_POST I'm getting a string from rfile.read(length) which looks like some sort of multipart MIME string.  Google is not being helpful on how I can decode this into something usable.

The output looks like this :

> ```
> -----------------------------122422713313797828591978698502
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"
>
>
>
> 1000000
>
> -----------------------------122422713313797828591978698502
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="and_title_input"
> ```

and so on.

I've tried email.parser

```
from email.parser import Parser 
p=Parser()
msg=p.parsestr(s)
```

but msg doesn't seem to get me any nearer to my goal - it's not multipart and contains no payload.

I'm reduced to parsing the data myself - which is surely not the Pythonic way of doing things!

Have I missed something obvious?  Has Google let me down?  Can Stack Overflow save the day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would [cgi.parse_multipart](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_multipart) meet your need? Also see a relevant discussion on [comp.lang.python](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/comp.lang.python/browse_frm/thread/27c73933aac26b0f/d2e77d5af8c801b9).

Comment: Yup - cgi.parse_multipart was the answer, and your link to comp.lang.python was very informative.  Thanks for that.  Hours of time saved, for something better!