# extract json data from post body request with python

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, extract, http-post

Is there a way to easily extract the json data portion in the body of a POST request? 
For example, if someone posts to www.example.com/post with the body of the form with json data, my GAE server will receive the request by calling:

```
jsonstr = self.request.body
```

However, when I look at the jsonstr, I get something like :

```
str: \r\n----------------------------8cf1c255b3bd7f2\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="Actigraphy"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-
stream\r\n\r\n{"Data":"AfgCIwHGAkAB4wFYAZkBKgHwAebQBaAD.....
```

I just want to be able to call a function to extract the json part of the body which starts at the {"Data":...... section.

Is there an easy function I can call to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a misunderstanding, the string you show us is not json data, it looks like a POST body. You have to parse the body with something like [cgi.parse_multipart](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_multipart).
Then you could parse json like answered by aschmid00. But instead of the body, you parse only the data.

Here you can find a [working code that shows how to use cgi.FieldStorage for parsing the POST body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9810738/1284193).
This Question is also [answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236597/parsing-python-html-post-data-from-basehttpserver).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how it was encoded on the browser side before submitting, but normally you would get the POST data like this:

```
jsonstr = self.request.POST["Data"]
```

If that's not working you might want to give us some info on how "Data" was encoded into the POST data on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
import json
values = 'random stuff .... \r\n {"data":{"values":[1,2,3]}} more rnandom things'
json_value = json.loads(values[values.index('{'):values.rindex('}') + 1])
print json_value['data'] # {u'values': [1, 2, 3]}
print json_value['data']['values'] # [1, 2, 3]
```

but this is **dangerous** and takes a fair amount of assumptions, Im not sure which framework you are using, bottle, flask, theres many, please use the appropriate call to `POST` 
 to retrieve the values, based on the framework, if indeed you are using one.

I think you mean to do this `self.request.get("Data")` If you are using the GAE by itself.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get_all